# LiquidFun on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I can't seem to get LiquidFun into my Android project in Eclipse.
For someone who never used the Android NDK the instructions are very unclear and upon trying to import LiquidFun or a LiquidFun example the NDK responds with

> 16:44:28 **** Clean-only build of configuration Default for project
>   Testbed ****
>   "C:\AndroidSDK\android-sdk-windows\AndroidNDK\ndk-build.cmd" clean
>   Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory:
>   C:/Users/Add/Desktop/Java-Projects/Libraries/LiquidFun/liquidfun
>   Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory:
>   C:/Users/Add/Desktop/Java-Projects/Libraries/LiquidFun
>   jni/Android.mk:35: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
>   Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'Box2D/jni' in import path
>   Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly
>   defined ?
>   Android NDK: The following directories were searched:
>   Android NDK:
>
> 16:44:29 Build Finished (took 655ms)

First I did what was described in the NDK documentation included in the download
1. (Downloaded the NDK)
2. Linked the NDK in the Eclipse properties
3. Imported a NDK testproject ("HelloJNI") into Eclipse
4. Pressed "Add Native Support" in Eclipse (rightclick on the project)
5. Run -> Run As -> Android Application

This worked as intended, so I tried the same with the LiquidFun "Testbed" example as described in the bit sparse LiquidFun Doc here
http://google.github.io/liquidfun/Building/html/md__building_android.html
1. Imported the "Testbed" folder/project into eclipse
2. Pressed "Add Native Support" in Eclipse (rightclick on the project)
3. Run -> Run As -> Android Application
However the log just shows up what I have written at the beginning of this post and Eclipse shows "Your project contains errors, fix them before running the project"

When I try to do "exactly" what the LiquidFun doc describes by opening the cmd and run npk-build in the Box2D directory, it creates the usual files as it normally should but upon implementing the Testbed application then I get the exact same result as above.

What am I doing wrong? I did exactly what the NDK documentation AND the liquidfun documentation suggested and both ways failed.

Thank you very much

## liquidfun